# how to reload particular subview in UIView swift?

Tags: ios, uiview

In main `UIView`, I have 3 subviews. I want to refresh only one subview.

My problem, i took array in one subview when i want to remove index of array in subview and refresh it it wont be.

I did try this method.

1. `- (void)layoutSubviews`
2. `- (void)layoutIfNeeded`

As well as:

`- (void)setNeedsLayout`

Answer (score 0):

**You can create a delegate relationship between your UIVIew and UIViewController classes.** 
Then add the proper code inside delegate methods to reload the UIVIew.

Otherwise you can call `setNeedsDisplay` on your view thereby you're forcing it to redraw. That is not the correct way of doing this.

[Totorial to make Delegates](https://www.codementor.io/leoiphonedev/delegates-in-swift-hvim2n7s1)

Comment: how to create a delegate, any Link or Idea